# SonarQube - SSO only allow specific users access to SonarQube via Security group

Tags: sonarqube, single-sign-on

I am implementing SSO into our SonarQube. Due to our company having so many users I want to only allow users that are within a specific security group e.g. SonarUsers. To have access to SonarQube and would be associated with a SonarUsers SonarQube Group and the same for SonarAdmins.

How/Is this possible?

Using SonarQube 6.2 and SSO Plugin 1.5.1

Comment: Can you tell me more about this SSO Plugin ? From where it comes ? Because you can use the bundle SSO feature with HTTP headers => See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication

Comment: I was planning on using the built in LDAP Authentication. Using this plugin [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin)

Comment: It's not possible to have SSO with the LDAP plugin

Answer (score 1):

From a single-sign-on perspective, your only option would be to have your SSO system refuse to authenticate them. But that's probably not what you want.

On the SonarQube side, since you're delegating authentication your only option would be to refuse them permission to see anything once they've authenticated. Do that by restricting who can [Browse](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-ProjectPermissions) your projects